# flutter png and then create PDF file to printer

Tags: pdf, flutter, printing, png, barcode

I am working in new flutter project that capture a widget to PNG image with a barcode and a few text like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089690/flutter-capture-the-widget-to-image-and-then-create-pdf-file-to-printer) and send the data to the printer via native code. But I had many issues. For example printing is too slow with ios devices (android print speed is ok). So I decide to print from PDF for ios and I have a few questions:

1. which package do I have to use for printing the PDF.
2. also can u provide me with the correct code for converting to PDF

thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
Can you share some code you tried? Or the package you already use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/printing

examples from the package:

```
final doc = pw.Document();

doc.addPage(pw.Page(
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context context) {
    return pw.Center(
      child: pw.Text('Hello World'),
    ); // Center
  }));
```

then

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
  onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => doc.save());
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Me Later

```
 Future printPng() async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext!
          .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

      // if it needs repaint, we paint it.
      if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => printPng());
        return null;
      }

      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData? byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

      final imageToPrint = await flutterImageProvider(MemoryImage(pngBytes));
      final doc = pw.Document();
      doc.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Center(child: pw.Image(imageToPrint)); // Center
      }));
      await Printing.layoutPdf(
          onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => doc.save());
      return pngBytes;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```